# How to prove that $|f(b)-f(a)|\le\frac{1}{n}(b-a)^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> for any real numbers $x,y$ we have
>   $$f(y)-f(x)\le (y-x)^2$$
>
> show that: for any postive integer $n$,and any real numbers $a,b$,we have
>   $$|f(b)-f(a)|\le\dfrac{1}{n}(b-a)^2$$

My partial works :
since
$$f(\dfrac{x+y}{2})-f(x)\le\left(\dfrac{y-x}{2}\right)^2\tag{1}$$
$$f(y)-f\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)\le\left(\dfrac{y-x}{2}\right)^2\tag{2}$$
(1)+(2)

we have
$$f(y)-f(x)\le\dfrac{1}{2}(y-x)^2$$
the same methods we have
$$f(y)-f(x)\le\dfrac{1}{4}(y-x)^2$$
$$\cdots\cdots$$
$$f(y)-f(x)\le\dfrac{1}{2^n}(y-x)^2$$
But this reslut also  can't prove  my problem

Comment: What you want to show, as you put it, would mean $\;|f(a)-f(b)|\;$ is less than *any* positive number, and thus $\;f(a)=f(b)\;$ . I don't think you meant this.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes this is exactly what is meant here.

Comment: @Did So apparently it was though it wasn't clear, for me at least, from the question's wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function $f$ satisfies 
$$
 f(y)-f(x) \le \lvert x-y\rvert^2\quad\text{for all $x,y$},
$$
then interchanging $x$ and $y$ we obtain that 
$$
\lvert\, f(y)-f(x) \rvert\le \lvert x-y\rvert^2\quad\text{for all $x,y$}.
$$
Hence
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\le |x-y|\quad\text{for all $x,y$}.
$$
This implies that $f$ is everywhere differentiable and $f'(x)=0$, for all $x$. Thus $f$ is constant and thus $f(a)-f(b)=0$, for all $a,b$.

Comment: It's Very  Nice!+1,

Answer (score 4):

This question and some of its variants appear periodically on the site and regularly receive answers based on differentiability. This approach is not necessary.

In the present case, assume without loss of generality that $f(a)\lt f(b)$ and apply the hypothesis to each pair of points $a+\frac{k-1}n(b-a)$ and $a+\frac{k}n(b-a)$, yielding $$f\left(a+\frac{k}n(b-a)\right)-f\left(a+\frac{k-1}n(b-a)\right)\leqslant\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}.$$ Summing these from $k=1$ to $k=n$, one gets $$f(b)-f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{k}n(b-a)\right)-f\left(a+\frac{k-1}n(b-a)\right)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{n}.$$ Thus, $$|f(b)-f(a)|=f(b)-f(a)\leqslant\frac{(b-a)^2}{n}.$$ As noted in a comment, the next question usually asks to use this to show that $f$ is constant. In other words, $2$-Hölder continuity implies constancy. Likewise, for every $a\gt1$, $a$-Hölder continuity implies constancy.

Comment: Nice too+1 !Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Partition $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals.

$|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|\leq (x_{i+1}-x_i)^2=(\frac{1}{n}(b-a))^2=\frac{1}{n^2}(b-a)^2$

$|f(b)-f(a)|=|\sum_{i=0}^n(f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}))|\leq \sum_{i=0}^n(|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|) \leq \frac{1}{n}(b-a)^2$